# View pdf instead of download using PDF js

Tags: laravel, pdf, laravel-5, pdf.js

In my page, I'm trying to display a thumbnails of my pdf using PDF JS and it works on local, but when I upload my code in my webserver the pdf file is auto download.

In my local :
[image]

Code :

```
$(function() {  

        var filePath = "http://example.com/public/uploads/docs/Document_One_1.pdf";

        function Num(num) {
            var num = num;

            return function () {
                return num;
            }
        };

        function renderPDF(url, canvasContainer, options) {
            var options = options || {
                    scale: 1.1
                },          
                func,
                pdfDoc,
                def = $.Deferred(),
                promise = $.Deferred().resolve().promise(),         
                width, 
                height,
                makeRunner = function(func, args) {
                    return function() {
                        return func.call(null, args);
                    };
                };

            function renderPage(num) {          
                var def = $.Deferred(),
                    currPageNum = new Num(num);
                pdfDoc.getPage(currPageNum()).then(function(page) {
                    var viewport = page.getViewport(options.scale);
                    var canvas = document.createElement("canvas");
                    canvas.setAttribute("id","pdfCanvas"+num);
                    canvas.setAttribute("onclick","popCanvas('{{url('/dashboard/showcanvas')}}','"+document.getElementById('pdfPath').innerHTML+"','"+num+"');");
                    var ctx = canvas.getContext('2d');
                    var renderContext = {
                        canvasContext: ctx,
                        viewport: viewport
                    };

                    if(currPageNum() === 1) {                   
                        height = viewport.height;
                        width = viewport.width;
                    }

                    canvas.height = height;
                    canvas.width = width;

                    canvasContainer.appendChild(canvas);

                    page.render(renderContext).then(function() {                                        
                        def.resolve();
                    });
                })

                return def.promise();
            }

            function renderPages(data) {
                pdfDoc = data;

                var pagesCount = pdfDoc.numPages;
                for (var i = 1; i <= pagesCount; i++) { 
                    func = renderPage;
                    promise = promise.then(makeRunner(func, i));
                }
            }

            PDFJS.disableWorker = true;
            PDFJS.getDocument(url).then(renderPages);       
        };

        var body = document.getElementById("bodyofpdf");
        renderPDF(filePath, body);
    });
```

When I change the filepath url, for example: "https://www.tutorialspoint.com/bootstrap/bootstrap_tutorial.pdf", it works.

Can somebody help me ??

Sorry for my poor english.

Comment: Define what do you mean by "works" (and doesn't work)?

Comment: P.S. don't use "PDFJS.disableWorker = true;"

Comment: @async5 I mean works (the thumbnails is appear/generates) .. But it's done now after I changed the PHP version and tell the browser to open the PDF using this code "'Content-Disposition' => "inline; $filename"" in my controller..

Comment: but I had another problem,. the pdf file that I uploaded is in Dutch languages, after it's generated pdf to the canvas, every word change as boxes, like this [][][][] [][][] [][]..

Answer (score 0):

If you are using Laravel you can control the behaviour of the **routes**, including the one to a .pdf. For local files, browsers have a different behaviour by default than for no local files.

I have used a lot PDF.js and I don't know why do you link the user directly to the file, you could create like a view page where it gets a parameter like the id or the name of the book and then you load it with pdf.js. If you use an url with a file extension you will probably confuse the browser.

```
yourpage.com/books/view/{id_book}
```

Comment: I did this, in my javascript I change the path : var filePath = "{{url('/dashboard/pdfthumbs')}}" + "/" + document.getElementById('pdfPath').innerHTML;

and in my route : Route::get('/dashboard/pdfthumbs/{filename}', function($filename)
 {
     $file_path = 'public/uploads/docs/'.$filename;
     if (file_exists($file_path))
     {
         return url($file_path);
     }
     else
     {
         exit('Requested file does not exist on our server!');
     }
 })->where('filename', '[A-Za-z0-9\-\_\.]+');

Comment: Well, I can't debug the code for you but should check the source code generated and see which is the final filePath, can check manually if it exists or there is an error. The error can be in many places, especially when you combine JavaScript and PHP.

Comment: the filepath is right, maybe the javascript can't generate the thumbnails from route ..