# parameter is not well received in blade file from controller

Tags: laravel, controller, routes, pdf.js

I am trying to show up book in laravel. When book 1st loads it shows 1st page of book.. but when I click bookmark button it reloads page but don't show book again. I am using pdf.js .

My Javascript function:

```
function pdf( count , scale)
    {      console.log(count);

          pdfjsLib.getDocument('../uploads/{{$book->file_path}}').then (doc => {
          doc.getPage(count).then(page => {
                var myCanvas=document.getElementById('my-canvas');
                var context= myCanvas.getContext('2d');

                const viewport = page.getViewport(scale);
                 myCanvas.height = viewport.height;
                 myCanvas.width = viewport.width;

                page.render({
                    canvasContext: context,
                    viewport: viewport
                });
              });
         });     
    }
```

```
function bookmark()
    {
        var url= '{{route('save_bookmark', ['b_id' => ':b_id', 'p_no' => ':p_no'])}}';   
          url = url.replace(':b_id', book);
          url = url.replace(':p_no', count);
         document.location.href = url;
    }
```

My route:

```
Route::get("save_bookmark/{b_id}/{p_no}",'BookmarkController@create')->name('save_bookmark');
```

My controller:

```
public function create($b_id, $p_no)
    {
        $b=new bookmark;           
        $b->u_id=Auth::user()->id;
        $b->book_id=$b_id;
        $b->p_no=$p_no;
        $b->save();     
        $b=Book::find($b_id);
        return view('pages/readbook')->with('book', $b)->with('count',$p_no);   

    }
```

Everything is working fine when book 1st opens but after bookmark click it is not finding up book.. I have tested that book and count variables are well recieved.

Error:

```
GET http://localhost/BookLibrary/public/save_bookmark/uploads/51312.pdf 500 (Internal Server Error)
```

Any suggestions??

Comment: can you post the server log which says 500?

Comment: 1:1 Uncaught (in promise) e {name: "UnexpectedResponseException", message: "Unexpected server response (500) while retrieving …kLibrary/public/save_bookmark/uploads/51312.pdf".", status: 500}

Comment: this might be helpful for you, https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36392947/view-pdf-instead-of-download-using-pdf-js